# Dagger / Google Auto Factory: Deal with mix of Lazy and Provided Fields

Tags: android, dagger

So I have a bit of a problem, it seems that there is no good pattern to do something like this right now.

```
public class Person {

   @Lazy<Foo> protected mLazyFoo;

}

@AutoFactory(
   className = "ManFactory"
)
public class Man extends Person {

    Private Hammer mHammer;

    Man(@Provided Hammer hammer) {
       mHammer = hammer;
    }

}

// mLazyFoo is null!!!!!
Man man = ManFactory.create();
```

How exactly would I deal with this situation? It seems that mixing AutoFactory and things that don't depend on autofactory is impossible right now or you have to do something to always provide a constructor to ensure like all lazy components in parent classes, for example, can manually be constructed like this example.

```
 public class Person {

       protected Foo mLazyFoo;

       protected Person(Foo foo) {
           mLazyFoo = foo;
       }

    }

    @AutoFactory(
       className = "ManFactory"
    )
    public class Man extends Person {

        Private Hammer mHammer;

        Man(@Provided Hammer hammer, @Provided Foo foo) {
           mHammer = hammer;
           super(foo);
        }

    }
```

Still it would change the nature of the code. It almost seems like using Lazy and Provider is 100% against using AutoFactory.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which works for me. In your module you have to add:

```
@Module()
public class CoreModule {
  @Provides @Singleton Lazy<Foo> provideLazyFoo(Lazy<Foo> foo) {
    return foo;
  }
}
```

With this Dagger will find the `Lazy<Foo>`and it also loads the `Foo` instance lazy when you request it.